# How to create xml nodes with colon

Tags: c#, xml

I want an xml output as under

```
  <ExtendedData xmlns:section="http://svr:1245/contact/kml/section.xsd">
    <section:secid>svr_01</section:secid>
    <section:name>test</unit:name>
  </ExtendedData>
```

How can I achieve this? My code is as below but the output is not correct

```
var attribute = xDoc.CreateAttribute("section","secid","http://svr:1245/contact/kml/section.xsd");

XmlElement elementExtendedData = xDoc.CreateElement("ExtendedData");
elementPlacemark.AppendChild(elementExtendedData);

var elementSectionid = xDoc.CreateElement("section", "secid");
attribute.InnerText = UniqueID;
elementSectionid.Attributes.Append(attribute);
elementExtendedData.AppendChild(elementSectionid);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create the `ElementData` element add add the namespace prefix `xmlns:section`.  Then add your element with the correct prefix and namespace.

```
var extendedData = xDoc.CreateElement("ExtendedData");
extendedData.SetAttribute("xmlns:section", "http://svr:1245/contact/kml/section.xsd");

elementPlacemark.AppendChild(extendedData);

var secId = xDoc.CreateElement("section", "secid", "http://svr:1245/contact/kml/section.xsd");
secId.InnerText = "svr_01";

extendedData.AppendChild(secId);
```

If you have the option, I'd suggest using LINQ to XML instead, it's much nicer to work with:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://svr:1245/contact/kml/section.xsd";

var element = new XElement("ExtendedData",
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "section", ns),
    new XElement(ns + "secid", "svr_01")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  doc = new XmlDocument();
                XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes");
                XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;



                doc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, root);

                string url2 = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#";  //ds

                XmlNode element1 = doc.CreateElement(NodoRaiz, "Facturae", "http://www.facturae.es/Facturae/2014/v3.2.1/Facturae");
              

                XmlAttribute attr = doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns:ds");


                attr.Value = url2;


                element1.Attributes.Append(attr);
            




                doc.AppendChild(element1);
```